# Why is npm install not installing packages into /node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I npm install package, npm says that it successfully installed the package, but when I look for it in the node_modules folder, the package is not in the folder. When I npm install -g package, the package gets installed into the global /node_modules folder, so I have to drag the package from the global folder to the local folder.

Why is npm install not installing into my local /node_modules folder?

Comment: are you using vscode terminal to install the package?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` in the directory you're installing from?

Comment: I am using powershell in vscode terminal, and my package.json is in the same directory as /node_modules

Comment: If you `require` the package after installing it, does it error?

Comment: Aplet123 what do you mean by require?

Comment: If you run `require("package-name")` in a node instance after installing the package, does it find the package or does it error?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to resolve this problem, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17282).

First, try deleting your `package-lock.json` file. If you run `npm install` or `npm i` after that it should generate a brand new installation with no reference to an existing `package-lock.json` file.

If that doesn't work, try deleting your `node_modules` directory in your project. Then run `npm install` or `npm i`.

If THAT doesn't work, you should try deleting both the `node_modules` directory AND the `package-lock.json`. Then run `npm install` or `npm i`. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

step 1) `rm -rf ./node_modules` from your root directory.

step 2) `npm install`.

> The above commands first deletes your node_modules and then reinstalls all the packages that are found inside your package.json.

> This is the same problem I was facing, both the above commands resolved the problem in my case.

If the `above` solution does `not` work in your case :

The problem is :

Data is not being `fetched` from the `package.json`, you must check whether you have written the correct `statement` or `not` `inside` your `package.json`.